# How to get http requests made by android phone in android studio

Tags: java, android, http, packet, sniffing

I'm making a simple android application in which I want to list urls of requests made by an android phone. Is there any way to do that? Or is there any API which can do that type of task?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up nanohttpd server on 1 device and make calls to that device using retrofit or similar libraries.

See [nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)

[retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)